# react searchkit with material-ui (pagination is-disabled)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, material-ui

I have an issue with searchkit using with material-ui. Both of libraries needs reactjs, but different versions. First time, when i used only searchkit with react, my app worked good, with no errors and warnings. Then i connected material-ui to my app, and got warnings like so:

- warning.js:44 Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the `insetSubheader` prop on `List`. This is deprecated and will not work in the next major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party PropTypes library.
- warning.js:44 Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the `subheader` prop on `List`. This is deprecated and will not work in the next major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party PropTypes library.
- warning.js:44 Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the `subheaderStyle` prop on `List`. This is deprecated and will not work in the next major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party PropTypes library.
- warning.js:44 Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the `linkButton` prop on `EnhancedButton`. This is deprecated and will not work in the next major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party PropTypes library.
- Warning: Unknown prop `labelColor` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element. 
  in div (created by EnhancedButton)
  in EnhancedButton (created by Chip)
  in Chip (created by JobTitleComponent)
  in div (created by JobTitleComponent)
  in div (created by CardText)
  in CardText (created by JobTitleComponent)
  in div (created by Card)
  in div (created by Paper)
  in Paper (created by Card)
  in Card (created by JobTitleComponent)
  in div (created by JobTitleComponent)
  in div (created by JobTitleComponent)
  in JobTitleComponent (created by DescriptionComponent)
  in div (created by DescriptionComponent)
  in div (created by DescriptionComponent)
  in div (created by DescriptionComponent)
  in MuiThemeProvider (created by DescriptionComponent)
  in DescriptionComponent (created by FullDescription)

But the main thing, that searchkit pagination worked well. 
Versions of libraries that i used was

- "material-ui": "0.15.2",
- "react": "15.3.0"
- "react-dom": "15.3.0"
- "searchkit": "^0.10.0".

Then i updated all to the latest versions, and searchkit Pagination has disappeared. I still can see it in DOM, but component thinks, that there is only one page to show, and has class "is-disabled", amount of results is more than 100 and hitsPerPage={10} though. 
I tried to return to the previous versions of libraries and I've got the same warnings, but pagination is still disabled.
How can i fix that issue ? Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was with regression with lodash. 
Developers advised to use lodash@4.13.1, and if you use webpack, do this:
`resolve: {
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
      lodash: path.resolve('./node_modules/lodash')
    }
}`

Also they sad, they will fix that issue.