# searchkit pagination not displaying where to place "resolve" code with webkit

Tags: pagination, searchkit

Referencing  earlier question

Searchkit pagination not displaying. @artem-timofieiev share code here: [react searchkit with material-ui (pagination is-disabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847307/react-searchkit-with-material-ui-pagination-is-disabled/38849429)

Where exactly do I paste this code?

```
resolve: {
     alias: {
     react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
     lodash: path.resolve('./node_modules/lodash')
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think you'd be more likely to get an answer by commenting on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in you webpack config.. Mostly from the base

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,

  entry: {
    // Add as many entry points as you have container-react-components here
    App: './reactjs/App',
    vendors: ['react'],
  },

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./example/static/bundles/local/'),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
  },

  externals: [
  ], // add all vendor libs

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendors', filename: 'vendors.bundle.js', minChunks: Infinity }),
  ], // add all common plugins here

  module: {
    loaders: [] // add all common loaders here
  },

  resolve: {
      alias: {
      react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
     lodash: path.resolve('./node_modules/lodash')
   }
 },
}
```

Cheers....